# cygwin startxwin, then ssh into a different machine

Tags: linux, cygwin

i have a batch file on windows with the following line in it:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/startxwin;"
```

When i execute this from windows, it launches an xterm window (with xwin enabled) and from there i can ssh into our remote linux server.

What i would like to do is add the ssh command in the batch file so that from my windows desktop, i can simply click it, and end up ssh'ing into our remote Linux server. I have tried doing something like this:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/startxwin; ssh -Y my-remote-server xterm"
```

But doesn't seem to work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Even though I tried to provide an answer below, I think that this question would be better suited for Super User or Unix & Linux instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with the following modifications:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/startxwin & sleep 5; DISPLAY=:0 ssh -Y my-remote-server xterm"
```

First, `startxwin` doesn't daemonize itself, so you need to start it with `&` to ensure it runs in the background.

Then you need to export the correct `DISPLAY` enviornment, so that `ssh` will know which X11 server to connect to (my solution doesn't export the variable, but provides it to `ssh` only).

Then you need to wait for some seconds to be sure the X server started (`sleep 5` is a guess, works on my machine).

Then you actually start the `ssh` process that connects and executes to the remote server.

I don't know about the `run.exe` part, I don't have it in my `cygwin` installation, maybe in your environment it would also work with the following:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/startxwin & sleep 5; DISPLAY=:0 ssh -Y my-remote-server xterm"
```